# How to use multiprocessing in a loop in python to generate solutions quickly?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, or-tools

I haven't previously used multiprocessing in any of my programs and wanted to learn about how its implemented. I have access to a machine with 24 cores and for am currently working on an optimization project.

```
def compute_euclidean_distance_matrix(locations):
"""Creates callback to return distance between points."""
distances = {}
for from_counter, from_node in enumerate(locations):
    distances[from_counter] = {}
    for to_counter, to_node in enumerate(locations):
        if from_counter == to_counter:
            distances[from_counter][to_counter] = 0
        else:
            # Euclidean distance
            distances[from_counter][to_counter] = (int(
                math.hypot((from_node[0] - to_node[0]),
                           (from_node[1] - to_node[1]))))
return distances
```

This is code I am currently using to build a distance time matrix. With a dataset with 1000 or so points it generates an output quite quickly, but say I have a dataset with 50000 points, how can I use all the cores on my PC to compute this quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Modify your distance function to just calculate *one* value, and use that as the pool worker.

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
from collections import defaultdict
import multiprocessing
import math


def distance(fromto, locations):
    fromindex, toindex = fromto
    if fromindex == toindex:
        return (fromindex, toindex, 0.0)
    fn, tn = locations[fromindex], locations[toindex]
    return (fromindex, toindex, math.hypot((fn[0] - tn[0]), (fn[1] - tn[1])))


locations = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 9)]  # just an example...
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
worker = partial(distance, locations=locations)
distance = defaultdict(dict)

for fromindex, toindex, distance in pool.imap_unordered(
    worker, combinations_with_replacement(range(len(locations)), 2)
):
    distance[fromindex][toindex] = distance
```

Pool workers only get *one* argument, so we combine `fromindex` and `toindex` into a tuple.
For the same reason, we use `partial` to supply it with the `locations` list.

Using `combinations_with_replacement` is just an elegant way of generating the tuples for the pool:

```
In [1]: from itertools import combinations_with_replacement                                              

In [2]: locations = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 9)]                                                             
Out[2]: [(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 9)]

In [3]: list( combinations_with_replacement(range(len(locations)), 2) )                                  
Out[3]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```